# Working with images on iOS platform

Tags: ios, image

**Information:**
I want to do some tasks on images such as resize, crop, rotate  and so on.
I hope they could be objects so that I can manipulate them one by one easily. In development time we could run up to several images at the same time to working on, just a-little-like game programming.
I see there's several things to choose toghether with XCode:
- Cocoa (default?)
- Quartz2D
- OpenGL (ES 2.0?)
- Cocos2D/Box2D
I'm new to mobile development as well as iOS.

**Question:**
- Because I could choose only one to start with, which should I choose? Or are there any other libraries/frameworks?

Comment: why don't you make a simple test to decide which solution would be the best for your current application...?

Comment: @holex I prefer having some experienced advise then I can have them tested on my own. To a beginner like me, it's not easy to make a test simple enough to decide which. It could be good at 'simple' test by me but further practice may be a suffer. Don't you think so?

Comment: I think your personal experience can tell the most in every case. you can collect the information your experience from the official documentation which contains the advantages and limits, from test applications which shows you how easy or hard to implement the wished parts. If I would say _I prefer better this or that_ it is not sure my preferred way will be the best for you and your actual project.

Comment: @holex I got your point, thanks. But because I created a topic here, could you please provide me with your opinion? Acording to you, which one is better for  manipulating images objects task only?

Comment: I've many of games... some games haven't needed any special feature, just the default `Cocoa` touch features. other games wanted the `Quartz2D` because I worked with dynamic images, and it was the fastest solution for me, other games has `OpenGL` engine, because it is a very powerful 3D engine on the iPhone. I don't know anything about the kind of your game, I cannot suggest any sure thing.

Comment: @holex mine is not a game. Just a tool for you to working on images, for example, a album collection gives you ability to edit multi images at the same time. With your answer, I think Cocoa is enough for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Cocos2d [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) for a game and it was pretty easy to pick up and manipulate images on screen. As it is build on top of OpenGL it abstracts you away from the nuts and bolts. But also it might be a bit heavy for your needs.

So if you can do what you need in Cocoa then use that but if you need more then look at Cocos2d.

Comment: I think you are right. I love game programming and Cocos2D is far than what I need to do. I am planning on creating a small application to play with images. Thanks for your idea :)